# Bootstrap Accordeon inside php loop not diplay correctly

Tags: php, bootstrap-5

I tried to make an accordeon menu, but when I click on the menu it does not expand. I follow an example that it works well. Maybe I make a mistake somewhere I think

Note : I have just a category and one sub category, not more

Main Category
sub Category One
sub Category two
2nd Main Category
sub Category One
sub Category two

Below my php code :

```
        <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
<?php
$i = 0;
if (is_array($categories)) {
  foreach($categories as $racine) { 
  $i++;
?>

<?php
    if($categories[0]) {
?>
          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading<?php echo $i; ?>">
<?php
              if ($i == 1 || $i == 16) {
                $button = '<button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse'. $i .'" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse'. $i .'">';
              } else {
                $button = '<button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse' . $i . '" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse' . $i . '">';
              }
?>
              <?php echo $button; ?>
              <?php echo $racine['text']; ?>
              </button>
            </h2>

          </div>
<?php
    }
?>

<?php
  }
}
?>
        </div>
```

the html code. I think my problem could be inside the loop ?

```
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">

          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading1">
              <button class="accordion-button show" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse1">Apps</button>
            </h2>
          </div>


          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading2">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apps Catalog</button>
            </h2>
          </div>


          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading3">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apps Communication</button>
            </h2>
          </div>


          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading4">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse4">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apps Configuration</button>
            </h2>
          </div>


          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading5">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse5" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse5">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Apps Customers</button>
            </h2>
          </div>



          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading16">
              <button class="accordion-button show" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse16" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse16">Hooks</a>                            </button>
            </h2>
          </div>


          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading17">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse17" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse17">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Modules Hooks Admin - Dashboard                            </button>
            </h2>
          </div>


          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading18">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse18" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse18">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Modules Hooks Import</button>
            </h2>
          </div>

          <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading21">
              <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse21" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse21">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Modules Hooks Cart</button>
            </h2>
          </div>
        </div>
```

the function

```
 public function getLabelTree(int|string $parent_id = '0', string $spacing = '', array|string $exclude = '', array|string $category_tree_array = '', bool $include_itself = false): array
  {
    if (!\is_array($category_tree_array)) {
      $category_tree_array = [];
    }

    if ((\count($category_tree_array) < 1) && ($exclude != '0')) {
      $category_tree_array[] = [
        'id' => '0',
        'text' => $this->upgrade->getDef('text_top')
      ];
    }

    if ($include_itself) {
      $Qcategory = $this->upgrade->get('marketplace_categories', 'categories_name', ['id' => (int)$parent_id]);

      $category_tree_array[] = [
        'id' => $parent_id,
        'text' => $Qcategory->value('categories_name')
      ];
    }

    $Qcategories = $this->upgrade->db->prepare('select categories_id,
                                                       categories_name,
                                                       parent_id
                                                from :table_marketplace_categories
                                                where parent_id = :parent_id
                                                order by sort_order, categories_name
                                               ');

    $Qcategories->bindInt(':parent_id', $parent_id);
    $Qcategories->execute();

    while ($Qcategories->fetch()) {
      if ($exclude != $Qcategories->valueInt('categories_id'))
        $category_tree_array[] = [
          'id' => $Qcategories->valueInt('categories_id'),
          'text' => $spacing . $Qcategories->value('categories_name')
        ];

      $category_tree_array = $this->getLabelTree($Qcategories->valueInt('categories_id'), $spacing . '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;', $exclude, $category_tree_array);
    }

    return $category_tree_array;
  }
```

Comment: That's because there is nothing for the accordion to "expand", your HTML is not complete.  You're only creating the `accordion-header` but **not** the `accordion-body` inside each `accordion-item`. [See the example in the documentation.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/accordion/#example). If you could tell me what you expect to be inside each `accordion-item` I could help you further.

Comment: I have 2 categories (1 categories, 1 sub categories) displayed by <?php echo $racine['text']; ?> (result a function see above)

Comment: I still don't understand what you're tying to do here.  Accordions are not meant to be used as a menu, they're supposed to hold (hidden) content. I am saying that because Bootstrap has terrible menu's and so people often misuse their components. Please add an example how you want it to work, or give a link to the example you are following.  [If you look at this JSFiddle, which Option is it you want?](https://jsfiddle.net/nvfad095/)

Comment: I understand. This is option 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in my comments, for Bootstrap (V5.3) accordions to work you need an `accordion-body`.

Try the code below. This will print the "Main Category" in the `accordion-header` and each "Sub Category" as a `list-item` in the `accordion-body`. You can change/add HTML to your needs.

```
<?php
echo '<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">';

$i = 0;
foreach ($categories as $racine) {
  $i++;

  // if Main Category
  if ($i == 1 || $i == 16) {
    if($i != 1) {
      echo '</ul></div></div></div>';
    }   
    echo '<div class="accordion-item"><h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading-' . $i .'"><button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapse-' . $i .'" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-' . $i .'">' . $racine['text'] . '</button></h2>';
    echo '<div id="collapse-'. $i .'" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-'. $i .'" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample"><div class="accordion-body"><ul>';
  }

  // if Sub Category
  else {  
    echo '<li>' . $racine['text']  . '</li>';
  }
}
echo '</ul></div></div></div>';
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Note that the line `echo '</ul></div></div></div>'` is used twice because we need close each `accordion-item` before a new `accordion-item` is printed, but also after the `foreach()` loop. Because your `$category_tree_array` array is one dimensional, there is no way to avoid this duplicate line.

A better way would be to make `$category_tree_array` a multidimensional array (inside your `getLabelTree()` function) and then use an inner `foreach()` to loop through the subcategories of each main category. Then you can avoid that duplicate line as well as the `if ($i == 1 || $i == 16) { }` statement altogether.

Let me know if you need any help with that. In any case, the code above should do the trick.

Good luck.